# Determine second base of matrix $A=\:\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ if second base exists.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Let it $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ matrix of a linear operator L by standard base of space $R^2$.Does second base of same space exists such that linear operator has same matrix according to that second base. I know that is $L(x,y)=(2x-3y,x+y)$ and that second base exists,but I don't know how to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If the matrix is the same in the base $(u, v)$, it means that $L(u) = 2 u + v$ and $L(v) = -3 u + v$

Comment: If is u=(x,y),v=(z,w) after solving system I get z=-3y,y=x-w,z=3w-3x.I suppose that is x=3 and become y=-2,z=6,w=5.Only I want know that I must suppose one value and then search other values so that u,v are linear independent or other way to do that exist?

Comment: I found that for each $u = (x, y)\not = (0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a unique solution $v=(z, w)$, and $u$ and $v$ are always linearly independent.